# Calling Java from PHP vs shell - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, php, shell, unix

I have two java classes that reside in .../jtest/StepRegTest directory and include "package StepRegTest;" directive.

**Option 1**. I call it directly from shell:

```
[jtest]# java StepRegTest.Main
```

Everything works fine.

**Option 2**. I call java via PHP **exec**:

```
<?php
echo getcwd() . "\n";
exec("java StepRegTest.Main 2>&1", $output);
print_r( $output );
?>
```

The PHP file is in the same directory **jtest** as for the Option 1, when I call it from the shell. However, it returns an error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/quinncurtis/matpackjava/DMatBase**

The jar archive that refers to these missing classes is in the CLASSPATH. 
The import reference for that class is:

```
import com.quinncurtis.matpackjava.DDMat;
```

Note that everything works fine when I execute the code from the shell.

What is the problem here? Why does it work from the shell, but not from PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably your CLASSPATH is not set in the PHP version. Try this: `exec("export CLASSPATH=.;java StepRegTest.Main 2>&1", $output);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the CLASSPATH environment variable is being used, verify it's set at the time the php exec() call is made; it may be getting lost.

One easy way to check is this:

```
<?php
echo getcwd() . "\n";
exec("env", $output);
print_r( $output );
?>
```

To set the CLASSPATH variable in the php script, the following can be done:

```
putenv("CLASSPATH=/path/to/lib.jar");
```

Here's a page that describes putenv():

http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: Post as comment please. A question can never be an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I don't see CLASSPATH executing exec("env", $output); from PHP. But calling "env" from the shell returns all correct paths. Why is that? Where shall I declare all paths for PHP?

Comment: Not sure.  CLASSPATH must be set and exported when you are running from the shell, or java wouldn't see it.  So, is the php script not running directly from the same shell?  If setting the path in the php script is alright, I'll find the way to do that.

Comment: Great! setting CLASSPATH via "putenv" has fixed the issue. I still cannot understand why PHP cannot see all system vars that are clearly visible from the shell.

Comment: Still I am having another problem - PHP returns "Error: Could not find or load main class StepRegTest.Main". Executing exactly the same java command from the shell works fine though...

Comment: Can you setup a shell script that contains the paths, CLASSPATH variable, and then exec's the java command?  That could make it a lot easier to get working and the debug this type of issue (such as using `set -x` to see exactly what commands the shell executes)..